# How to regex in python?

Tags: python, xml, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse the keywords from google suggest, this is the url:

http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=test

I've done it with php using:

```
'|<CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="(.*?)"/><num_queries int="(.*?)"/></CompleteSuggestion>|is'
```

But that wont work with python re.match(pattern, string), I tried a few but some show error and some return None.

How can I parse that info? I dont want to use minidom because I think regex will be less code.

Comment: Can you post the python code that you are trying to use?

Comment: I'm sure python has a formidable XML parser. Why are you using regex?

Comment: @Kobi more than one actually.

Comment: I dont know how to parse it neither with regex or an xml parse, an example would be great. And my python code would be re.match(the pattern i posted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `etree`:

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser
>>> x = XMLParser()
>>> x.feed('<toplevel><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data=...')
>>> tree = x.close()
>>> [(e.find('suggestion').get('data'), int(e.find('num_queries').get('int')))
     for e in tree.findall('CompleteSuggestion')]
[('test internet speed', 31800000), ('test', 686000000), ...]
```

It is more code than a regex, but it also does more. Specifically, it will fetch the entire list of matches in one go, and unescape any weird stuff like double-quotes in the `data` attribute. It also won't get confused if additional elements start appearing in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

This is an XML document.  Please, reconsider an XML parser.  It will be more robust and probably take you less time in the end, even if it is more code.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to use an xml parser in python? I am in the same situation than with regex.

Comment: @jahmax: I think Marcelo Cantos, above, has done a solid job of showing a DOM-style XML parser operating in Python.